# If then Statement using Two Different Date Ranges

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, powerquery, m

In Power BI, I'm using a period table that applies steps to take today's date, sets up the ranges, transforms the ranges into a table, and then sets the output in Power Query. Everything works as it is supposed to but the focus is at the ranges step.

Here it is as is:

```
    = {
                    {"Day", 
                    Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-1), 
                    Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-1),
            1},
                    {"Week to Date", 
                    Date.From(Date.StartOfWeek(TodaysDate,Day.Thursday)), 
                    Date.AddDays( Date.From(Date.StartOfWeek(TodaysDate,Day.Thursday)) , +6), 
            2},
                    {"Week", 
                    Date.AddWeeks( Date.From(Date.StartOfWeek(TodaysDate,Day.Thursday)) , -1), 
                    Date.AddDays( Date.From(Date.StartOfWeek(TodaysDate,Day.Thursday)) , -1), 
....
```

Here is the example output:

[image]

What I want however, is that if today is equal to Monday, then only show the date for Friday. 
Here was my attempt:

```
= {
            {"Day", 
            if Date.DayofWeek(TodaysDate) = 1 
       then 
    [
            Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-3), 
            Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-3),
    ]
            else
    [
            Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-1), 
            Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-1),
    ] ....
```

Notice that "Day" is "Yesterday". 
I'm trying to get this done so people can see production for the previous day worked where the previous day for Monday would be Friday.

Here is the whole code:

```
    let
    TodaysDate = Date.From(DateTimeZone.FixedUtcNow()),
    Ranges = {
                {"Day", 
                Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-1),                 
                Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-1), 

        1},
                {"Week to Date", 
                Date.From(Date.StartOfWeek(TodaysDate,Day.Thursday)), 
                Date.AddDays( Date.From(Date.StartOfWeek(TodaysDate,Day.Thursday)) , +6), 
        2},
        {"Week", 
                Date.AddWeeks( Date.From(Date.StartOfWeek(TodaysDate,Day.Thursday)) , -1), 
                Date.AddDays( Date.From(Date.StartOfWeek(TodaysDate,Day.Thursday)) , -1), 
        3},
                {"Month To Date", 
                Date.From(Date.StartOfMonth(TodaysDate)), 
                TodaysDate, 
                4},
                {"Month", 
                Date.AddMonths(Date.From(Date.StartOfMonth(TodaysDate)),-1), 
                Date.AddMonths(Date.From(Date.EndOfMonth(TodaysDate)),-1), 
                5},
                {"Rolling 13Wks", 
                Date.AddWeeks(TodaysDate,-13) + #duration(1,0,0,0), 
                TodaysDate, 
                6},
                {"Year To Date", 
                Date.From(Date.StartOfYear(TodaysDate)), 
                TodaysDate, 
                7}

             },
    GetTables = List.Transform(Ranges, 
            each CreatePeriodTable(_{0}, _{1}, _{2}, _{3})),
    Output = Table.Combine(GetTables),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Output, each true)
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere. What exactly is the problem you are having trouble with?

Comment: I made an attempt to do an if statement and it was wrong. I don't know the proper syntax in power query to do an if statement for "if today is Monday then date will be friday else date is today - 1." How do I make my attempt above work?

Comment: What do you want your result to look like and why are you writing things twice?

Comment: say today is Monday, 5/20/19. The date I want to show up a "Day" is 5/17/19 since that was the last work day. I added the whole code up top but a "range" is required to avoid an error.

Comment: I still have no idea what you want your final table to look like. The same format as your screenshot?

Comment: Yes, everything else works how I want it to for the other periods but I want to display for the Day row: Previous Friday's date on Monday, Monday's date on Tuesday, Tuesday's date on Wednesday etc. I'm sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest thing would be to create a variable for the previous day:

```
let
    TodaysDate = Date.From(DateTimeZone.FixedUtcNow()),
    PrevWorkDate = if Date.DayOfWeek(TodaysDate) = 1
                   then Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-3)
                   else Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-1),

    Ranges = {
                {"Day", 
                PrevWorkDate,                 
                PrevWorkDate, 

        1},

    [...etc...]
```

---

Otherwise, you might be able to do something like this:

```
let
    TodaysDate = Date.From(DateTimeZone.FixedUtcNow()),
    Ranges = {
        if Date.DayOfWeek(TodaysDate) = 1
        then
            {"Day", 
                Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-3), 
                Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-3),
             1}
        else
            {"Day", 
                Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-1), 
                Date.AddDays(TodaysDate,-1),
             1},
```